# Negative power won't work in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

When applying this formula:

```
=(C40-G40)^(-0.25)
```

I get an invalid function error.

However, when doing:

```
=(C40-G40)^(2)
```

or with a negative number:

```
=(C40-G40)^(-2)
```

It works fine. It seems like the -0.25 is the issue. Any particular reason why this can't work ? 
C40-G40 equals to about 500

Answer (score 2):

No, it works. I tried with `=500^(-0.25)` without problems.

I think your `C40-G40` is a negative value, so it is not a valid mathematical operation (with real numbers).